# How much less kernel overhead Tesla is, comparing to Geforce?

Tags: c, cuda, kernel, nvidia

Tesla(Fermi or Kepler) with TCC mode comparing to Geforce (same generations) with WDDM?

The program I wrote have some very serious problems with kernel overheads due to it have to repeatively lanuch kernels, the overhead is so huge I have to merge many kernels togegther and trade memory space for less kernel launches, however it can only work so far thanks to the grand size of GPU memory storage.

I heard TCC mode can have less overheads, but can it bring the overhead performane to CPU'level?

Since I read some benchmarks, at least for Geforce 280 GTX the kernel-call overheads is thousands of times longer than function-call overheads of CPU, and for methods require a large amount of repeatively iterations it make a huge performance difference here.

Comment: Can you switch to Windows XP ? you will not have WDDM issues there.

Answer (score 1):

The WDDM driver will batch kernel launches together to reduce overhead. So if you are able to merge kernels together to reduce launch overhead, so will be the WDDM driver as well (unless you use CUDA calls in between that prevent batching). Thus switching to TCC mode will not gain you much in this specific use case.

Are you sure the problem is launch overhead and not something else? How many separate kernels are you launching and how long does this take?
It could well be (particularly in the case of very small kernels where launch overhead would be noticable) that merging the kernels together allows the compiler to better optimize the kernels, e.g. to eliminate the writing out and reading back of intermediate results to global memory.

Comment: If your problem is latency not throughput then batching will indeed not help but even be counterproductive. I don't see though how merging kernels would help then either.

Comment: @user0002128 If you are trying to launch 100 million kernels than you are doing something wrong. You do not seem to understand how accelerators work and for what type of problems they are suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I was launching 16 kernels and the speed was X when I merged all kernels to be launched at once the speed was 10X also merging kernels has put overhead but the results were great.

This is many-core architecture if you cannot make use of that (launch the largest job size) then you are wasting the overhead you took to launch the kernel.

I hope this helps you.